# E0145 Member may not be initialized- cmake - VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, point-cloud-library

I am trying to link a C++ application with PCL library. I installed PCL and all its dependencies using VCPKG. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and cmake 3.12 for X64. When I am trying to build the solution it is giving me the following Errors.

```
E0145   member "boost::filesystem::path::separator" may not be initialized 
C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64- 
windows\include\boost\filesystem\path.hpp   65  

E0145   member "boost::filesystem::path::preferred_separator" may not be 
initialized C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64- 
windows\include\boost\filesystem\path.hpp   66  

E0145   member "boost::filesystem::path::dot" may not be initialized 
C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64- 
windows\include\boost\filesystem\path.hpp   67  

E2512   the argument to a feature-test macro must be a simple identifier 
C:\vcpkg-pcl\vcpkg-master\installed\x64- 
windows\include\boost\system\error_code.hpp 401
```

On the console I find this error, eventhough I installed Pthreads library using VCPKG and set the PTHREADS_INCLUDE variable

```
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
```

This is my CMakelists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(compute_parameters)
find_package(PCL 1.5 REQUIRED)
SET(PTHREADS_INCLUDE "${PTHREADS_ROOT}/include")
find_path (PTHREADS_INCLUDE "pthread.h" NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS};${PTHREADS_INCLUDE})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (compute_parameters compute_parameters.cpp)
target_link_libraries (compute_parameters ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I fixed the first three errors (E0145) by #define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_SOURCE in my application. The last error (E2512) remains. It occurs in the following code: `#define BOOST_SYSTEM_REQUIRE_CONST_INIT

#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute)
#if __has_cpp_attribute(clang::require_constant_initialization)
# undef BOOST_SYSTEM_REQUIRE_CONST_INIT
# define BOOST_SYSTEM_REQUIRE_CONST_INIT [[clang::require_constant_initialization]]
#endif
#endif`