# Problems with Boost when using Point Cloud Library (PCL)

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library

I work under Windows 10 64 bit and use Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.5). Via vcpkg I got PCL with all dependencies installed (vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows). I have the versions: BOOST 1.68.0, PCL 1.9.1-1.

For example, if I just add `#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>`, I get:

```
E0145   member "boost::filesystem::path::separator" may not be initialized 

E0145   member "boost::filesystem::path::preferred_separator" may not be initialized 

E0145   member "boost::filesystem::path::dot" may not be initialized 

E2512   the argument to a feature-test macro must be a simple identifier 

E0434 A reference of type "boost::filesystem::path::iterator &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with "boost::filesystem::path::iterator"
```

Inserting `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_SOURCE` from [E0145 Member may not be initialized- cmake - VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737774/e0145-member-may-not-be-initialized-cmake-vs2017/54200907#54200907) looks like it's fixing the E0145 error.  I still have the E2512 and E0434.

I searched Boost, PCL and other repositories for solutions but found nothing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the project file (accessed using the project properties property sheet), C/C++ section, 'General' entry, you have the Additional Include Directories field, where you can set the search path for the header files.